How to Execute Commands and Retrieve Responses from an Azure VM Using Azure Node.js SDK
I'm currently working on a project where I need to execute commands on an Azure Virtual Machine (VM) and retrieve the responses, all through a Node.js application. I'm aware that the Azure Node.js SDK offers a range of functionalities to manage Azure resources, but I'm not sure if it supports this specific use case.
My requirements are:

Connect to an Azure VM.
Execute shell commands (e.g., Bash commands for Linux or PowerShell commands for Windows).
Retrieve the output of those commands in my Node.js application.

Is it possible to execute commands on an Azure VM and get the response back using the Azure Node.js SDK?
If not directly through the SDK, what is the recommended approach to achieve this functionality within a Node.js application?

AFAIK, it won't display the inside VM output details from outside when you are using any script.
